# What is the difference between Redmine versions 3.x and 2.x

Tags: redmine

I have done quite a bit of looking on the Redmine website, and executed a number of Google searches, but I have not been able to find an answer to the difference between Redmine 2.x and Redmine 3.x

I imagine that, much like Redmine 1 vs Redmine 2, it has to do with the version of Rails that the platform is built on, but I would be interested to know a little more in-depth about the differences and compatibility.

I imagine, also, that plugins are not compatible between the two versions, so this leaves one to wonder, what are the benefits of using one over the other?

Edit: I do see the Rails version difference listed on the [Installation page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall).  What is the difference beyond that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We using Redmine at work, with version 2.3.3
And now we wanted to upgrade to new versions (security updates).
We asked the same question.

And what I founded:

from their [news page](http://www.redmine.org/news/95)

> This **new** version brings *several improvements to the **search engine*** (it's now much faster and includes new search options) and many new features: **default issue status per tracker**, **multiple emails per user**, **ability to edit attachment descriptions** and [more](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Changelog)

from their [Changelog](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Changelog)

> ...
>
> Feature #13849: Grouped filters in the filter drop-down
>
> Feature #13051: Support any macro in (pdf) export for wiki's and issues
>
> Feature #12097: Multi Thread Support
>
> Feature #8818: Repository user-mapping with multiple email addresses
>
> Feature #11702: Add user/group to multiple projects at once
>
> Feature #4244: Multiple email addresses for each user
>
> Feature #1326: Add / edit an attachment description after upload
>
> ...

and more